# Error in this line: Example Obj2 = new Example (Obj1);

Tags: java

I have a Java program . But an error shows in this line `Example Obj2 = new Example (Obj1);`  I cannot find the error. Please solve this problem.

```
class Example
{
  int a,b;
  Example(int x,int y)
  {
    a=x;
    b=y; 
  }
  void Display()
  {
     System.out.println("Values" +a +b);
  }
}

public class Copy
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Example Obj1=new Example(10,20);
    Example Obj2= new Example (Obj1);   // Error in this line ,please solved this problem

    Obj1.Display();
    Obj2.Display();
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no constructor with a similar definition `new Example (Obj1)`

Comment: try this **Example obj2=obj1.clone()**

Comment: @holidayCoder um no.

Comment: @shmosel why that?

Comment: @holidayCoder try it.

Comment: @Zahidul please mark an answer to the thread or update accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Example Obj2= new Example (Obj1.a, Obj1.b);
```

might help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a constructor overload that accepts `Example`:

```
class Example {
    int a,b;

    Example(int x,int y) {
        a=x;
        b=y;
    }

    Example(Example copy) {
        this(copy.x, copy.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: as per requirement its a clever approach but whats wrong with cloning?

Comment: @holidayCoder there are several problems with cloning in Java, as a quick search will show you. But in this particular case I was just trying to make OP's instantiation work as-is. If you're referring to my response to your comment, you can't call `clone()` without overriding it and implementing `Cloneable`, as a simple test would have demonstrated.